# form registers as valid but does not update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is a very weird phenomenon. Why is it that even though the form is valid, the values are not updated? It works if i do it in django admin though. I am not even receiving any errors. The form is just valid but its not being updated. Its as if they took the old values to update...

html:

```
<form action="{% url 'account:displayinfo' request.user.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-lg-5">Update</button>
</div>

</form>
```

views.py

```
def display_information_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    context = {}
    displayinfo = AccountDisplayInfo.objects.get(account=account)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DisplayInformationForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            info = form.save(commit=False)
            info.account = request.user
            info.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile display information have been updated', extra_tags='editdisplayinfo')
            return redirect("account:view", user_id=account.pk)
        else:
            form = DisplayInformationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user,   
        initial={
            "instagram": displayinfo.instagram,
        }
       )

            context['form'] = form
    else:
        form = DisplayInformationForm(
        initial={
            "instagram": displayinfo.instagram,
            }
       )
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "account/displayinfo.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class DisplayInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountDisplayInfo
        fields = ('instagram',)
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class AccountDisplayInfo(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True) #instagram


@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def create_AccountDisplayInfo(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        AccountDisplayInfo.objects.create(account=instance)
```

Comment: are you facing any error?

Comment: no errors faced. the success message is shown after the "update" @c.grey

Comment: any idea? @c.grey

Comment: @kknam As a note you use `get(account=account)` to get the instance of `AccountDisplayInfo` indicating that only one instance of it exists for one user. In this case instead of `models.ForeignKey` you should be using [`models.OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) instead to indicate the one to one relationship between the two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the instance of the form to the incorrect model instance. Looking at your form it is a `ModelForm` for `AccountDisplayInfo` yet you pass the instance as `instance=request.user`. Change all such code to `instance=displayinfo`.

Comment: do I need to change the signals that I have written in models.py to `instance=displayinfo`?

Comment: @kknam That depends on what the signals are expecting / doing, etc.

Comment: i'm making it such that when i create an account object, an accountdisplayinfo object will be automatically created

Comment: @kknam You don't need a form to do that anyway `dsiplayinfo = AccountDisplayInfo(account=instance)` and then `displayinfo.save()` should be enough?